# IO with port manipulation while not interfering with i2c

Tags: i2c, attiny

I'm using an Attiny84 with the Tiny Core. 
I'm try to use port manipulation to write the lower four bits of port A. I'm using i2c which occupies bits 5 and 7.

How can I write only to the lower 4 bits to avoid interfering with the i2c?

Comment: Have you tried doing it, and it has not worked?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to worry. A simple piece of code:

```c++
void setup() 
{
 PORTA |= bit (0);
}

void loop() { }
```

Generates:

```
00000044 <setup>:
  44:   d8 9a           sbi 0x1b, 0 ; 27
  46:   08 95           ret
```

In other words, the compiler generates code to set that bit, ignoring all the other bits.

Comment: Presumably PORTA |= bit (0000); would set the 4 least significant bits?

Comment: Not at all. Zero is zero, no matter how many leading zeroes you put there. You could do this:  `PORTA |= 0b00001111;`

Comment: The `bit` macro sets a bit by shifting the number `1` left the number of bits in the argument, so `bit (0)` is `1 << 0` which is the same as `1`.

Comment: OK, so I understand now that I can set the bits to 1 without touching the i2c pins. Is it the same, but I suppose with the OR operator to set back to 0?

Comment: No, you use the AND operator. `PORTA &= ~0b00001111;` The `~` operator takes the ones-complement, and you AND that into the port. Alternatively: `PORTA &= 0b11110000;`